# Using windows authentication in IIS

Tags: authentication, iis, windows-authentication

i am trying to use windows authentication in IIS.
i have it set up and can Deny specific folders.
I get a 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials as expected however i do not get the popup asking me to enter my username and password.

as stated above the problem is in am not getting a dialog asking me for user and password.

Answer (score 0):

If you put **Deny** then it'll be always unavailable. You need to put **Allow** rule and specify roles. In case you need it to be accessible by everyone - use built-in **Everyone** group. But note that if you have **Windows Authentication** enabled - it might authenticate you automatically without asking credentials. As one of the options to force behavior you need - leave **Basic Authentication** enabled only.